# Not to focus Main form (with a timer)

Tags: vb.net, timer, vb.net-2010

[image: My Mainform and conversation form]

my mainform has a timer that will update my online and offline panel(it is running every 2secs interval), it will only update if it reads a new data in my database.
when im having conversation with someone, if my mainform reads a new data from database
then my mainform's panels will update. after updating the focus will be set to my main form.

help not to focus my mainform everytime my mainform update.
thanks a lot.

Comment: A Timer does not focus anything.  You'll need to fix the bug in your code.  Screenshots are a unhelpful way to show bugs in code.

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

Look, it's not clear that exactly what you want but you can try the following code. Make your mainform (Whatever name it is) hidden and then use the `SetFocus` control. This will shift the focus to the form you want.

In addition to this, you can also use the GotFocus and LostFocus events. Like if mainform lost focus, what to do.

## Code and Example

```
mainform.Hide()
Form2.SetFocus() 'The form name here you want to set focus to.
```

Hope it will work perfectly!